# mongodb service does not start

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I did a `mongodb` `4.2.1` fresh install on my digital occean `ubuntu 18.04 LTS` droplet. For some weird reason the service daemon does not start.

```
019-12-05T11:35:31.148+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] ***** SERVER RESTARTED *****
2019-12-05T11:35:31.153+0000 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-12-05T11:35:31.167+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=1291 port=27017 dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb 64-bit host=ubuntu-s-1vcpu-2gb-blr1-01
2019-12-05T11:35:31.167+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.1
2019-12-05T11:35:31.167+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: edf6d45851c0b9ee15548f0f847df141764a317e
2019-12-05T11:35:31.167+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
2019-12-05T11:35:31.167+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-12-05T11:35:31.167+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-12-05T11:35:31.167+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-12-05T11:35:31.167+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1804
2019-12-05T11:35:31.167+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-12-05T11:35:31.167+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-12-05T11:35:31.167+0000 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "0.0.0.0", port: 27017 }, processManagement: { timeZoneInfo: "/usr/share/zoneinfo" }, storage: $
2019-12-05T11:35:31.169+0000 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Unable to read the storage engine metadata file: FileNotOpen: Failed to read metadata from /var/lib/mongodb/storage.bson
2019-12-05T11:35:31.169+0000 F  -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 28661 at src/mongo/db/storage/storage_engine_metadata.cpp 89
2019-12-05T11:35:31.169+0000 F  -        [initandlisten]
```

Comment: take a look at this steps to install mongodb

Comment: I tried exactly the same steps. If I install the `3.6` version it works. Don't know what breaks for ` 4.2.1`

Comment: Try 'apt --fix-broken install'

Answer (score 1):

`Unable to read the storage engine metadata file: FileNotOpen: Failed to read metadata from /var/lib/mongodb/storage.bson` - the file format from v3.6 is not suitable for v4.2.

Read [how to upgrade](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/4.2-upgrade-standalone/). Essentially:

> To upgrade from a version earlier than the 4.0-series, you must successively upgrade major releases until you have upgraded to 4.0-series. For example, if you are running a 3.6-series, **you must upgrade first to 4.0 before** you can upgrade to 4.2.